# Concatenating vectors, append() vs c()

Tags: r

When concatenating two vectors, `a` and `b`, in R, it seems to me that

```
append(a,b)
```

and

```
c(a,b)
```

produces the same result. Are there any cases where one of the functions should be preferred over the other? Is `append()` meant for operations on lists rather than vectors?

Comment: Append can be useful in `for` loops if you want to add each new thing generated by iterations to your output vector

Comment: @RStudious `c` can equally well be used here. However, neither is actually good code: appending to a vector in a loop is *very inefficient*, and also not very readable — this is usually (always?) better solved by using `*apply` type functions.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Thank you, that was useful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the `append()` function. Basically it is the addition of the `after` argument that sets it apart. In general, `c()` will be more efficient since it skips this little bit of logic.

```r
function (x, values, after = length(x)) 
{
    lengx <- length(x)
    if (!after) 
        c(values, x)
    else if (after >= lengx) 
        c(x, values)
    else c(x[1L:after], values, x[(after + 1L):lengx])
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. `append` is a badly named function — it should be called `insert`, and should in general not be used for *appending* (since `c` does the same, more efficiently) but rather only when inserting in the middle of a vector.